# ¿Cómo cambiar una instancia de RDS en AWS publica?

Tags: sql-server, aws

Estoy tratando de acceder a una instancia de SQL Server creada en AWS, ya agregue la regla de entrada para que me permita conectar a través del puerto 1433 pero no puedo obtener la conexión hacía el servidor. De igual manera ya realicé un PING y un TELNET. El PING si responde pero el TELNET a ese puerto no me da ninguna respuesta. ¿Que podría estar sucediendo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esa es la regla que añado

Comment: Estas seguro que SQL Server está configurado para usar ese puerto? Una cosa es que habilites el security group o ACL y otra que la instancia esté escuchando en ese puerto.

Comment: Así es https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2109/loki, el servidor esta configurado para recibir peticiones a través de ese puerto

Comment: Es EC2 o RDS? Esta dentro de una VPC? Podría estar detras de un NAT y estaría cambiandote el puerto.

Comment: Es RDS y si esta dentro de una VPC

Comment: El la pergunta mencionas una regla. Si es NACL recuerda que tienes que crear la regla de entrada y salida. Si es SG con la de entrada basta.

Comment: Solamente es security group pero no consigo la conexión

Comment: También tienes que modificar esto. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que son herramientas totalmente diferentes.

Ping se basa en la capa ICMP. Esta capa, por ejemplo, no entiende el concepto de puerto. El comando ping simplemente lanza una petición y se queda esperando a ver si obtiene una respuesta a nivel de red ... y ya está.

telnet es un protocolo de red que permite la ejecución remota de comandos.

Ping te funciona, posiblemente porque estás intentando acceder a un endpoint de AWS, es decir, hay una máquina de AWS con la que consigues contactar con el ping

Telnet no te funciona por.... vete tu a saber:

- El SG de la instancia está bloqueando la conexión
- El endpoint al que te intentas conectar no es el correcto
- otros motivos ...

Podrías empezar por mirar el siguiente enlace

https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/